# Writing to file is creating empty list on every second entry

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple Login system and save the username and passwords to a file. The first item is the Login and the second is the password. It works fine mostly except when I run it every other time it writes an empty list onto the file. What am I doing wrong here?

Eminem,Killer,
[],[],
Skyler,Grey,
[],[],
Dr,Dre,
[],[],
Easy,E,

```
def Createuser():
    user = open('File','r')
    UN = []
    PW = []
    pw1 = []
    pw2 = []
    TUN = []
    TPW = []
    c = []
    D = []
    def createpw():
        pw1 = input('Enter your password',)
        pw2 = input('verify your password',)
        if pw1 == pw2:
            print("Successful")
            return(pw1)
        else:
            print("Passwords do not match")
            createpw()
    for i in user:
        a = i.split(",")
        b = list(zip(a))
        UN.append(a[0])
        PW.append(a[1])
    ##print(UN)
    ##UN = list(zip(UN))
    ##PW = list(zip(PW))
    x = input('Enter your Username',)
    print(x)
    if x in UN:
        print ("User name ",x, " already exists")
        Createuser()
    else:
        TUN = x
        print("Successful")
        TPW = createpw()
    print(UN)
    UN.append(TUN)
    PW.append(TPW)
    print (UN)
    print (PW)
    c = (UN,PW)
    print("this is c",c,'end')
    D = list(zip(*c))
    print('this',D,'was d')
    with open('File','w') as f:
        for item in D:
            f.write('%s,%s,\n' % item)
```

Comment: Which language do you talking about?

Comment: The fact that your format string is `'%s,%s,\n'`, but you only pass it one arg (`item`) is a bit suspicious.

Comment: Actually, @0x5453. in this case that's OK.  D is a list of 2-tuples.

Comment: @0x5453 If `item` were a single value, that would have raised an exception.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem.  When I run your code, the file grows by one line each time with no extras.

Comment: And, by the way, recursive calls are not the right way to do that kind of validation.  Use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: I figured out what causes the problem. It only happens when you enter a username that already exists so the program asks you to enter your username again. Not sure why that should cause the issue though

Answer (score 1):

Consider reorganizing your problem like this, without recursion:

```
def createpw():
    while True:
        pw1 = input('Enter your password ')
        pw2 = input('verify your password ')
        if pw1 == pw2:
            print("Successful")
            return pw1
        print("Passwords do not match")

def Createuser():
    user = open('pw.txt','r')
    UN = []
    PW = []
    for i in user:
        a = i.split(",")
        UN.append(a[0])
        PW.append(a[1])
    while True:
        x = input('Enter your Username ')
        print(x)
        if x not in UN:
            break
        print ("User name ",x, " already exists")
    print("Successful")
    TUN = x
    TPW = createpw()
    UN.append(TUN)
    PW.append(TPW)
    print (UN)
    print (PW)
    D = list(zip(UN,PW))
    print('this',D,'was d')
    with open('pw.txt','w') as f:
        for item in D:
            f.write('%s,%s,\n' % item)

Createuser()
```

Comment: Cheers Tim. Will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Cheers Tim. That seems to have done the trick. Must have been the recursive calls messing it up. Really appreciate it